# The effect of the non-existense of longitudinal polarisation mode of the photon on equipartition theorem

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, photons, mass, degrees-of-freedom

Massless vector bosons like photons only have 2 independent polarisation degrees, unlike massive vector bosons. For a spin 1 boson with mass $\mu$ and with $k^λ = (ω, 0, 0, k)$ the longitudinal mode is given by $ε_λ^{(3)} = (−k, 0, 0, ω)/\mu$. In the limit $\mu\to 0$ this longitudinal mode cannot exist and there will only be 2 internal degrees of freedom.

So because of that when we apply the equipartition theorem we get only $2/3$rd of the value of the total energy compared to a particle that is massive.

A Zee in QFT in a nutshell (Pg $150$) says that

> Here is an apparent paradox. Mr. Boltzmann tells us that in thermal equilibrium each degree of freedom is associated with $\frac{1}{2}T$ . Thus, by measuring some thermal property (such as the specific heat) of a box of photon gas to an accuracy of $2/3$ an experimentalist could tell if the photon is **truly massless rather than have a mass of a zillionth of an electron volt**.
>
> The resolution is of course that as the coupling of the longitudinal mode vanishes as $μ → 0$ the time it takes for the longitudinal mode to come to thermal equilibrium goes to infinity. Our crafty experimentalist would have to be very patient.

Why will it take $\infty$ time to measure the energy or specific heat?

Comment: The quote seems to already answer this: *"as the coupling of the longitudinal mode vanishes as μ → 0"* Can you be more specific what's unclear about this?

Comment: @ACuriousMind that sentence is not clear to me. "*the time it takes for the longitudinal mode to come to thermal equilibrium goes to infinity*" why will it go to $\infty$ if coupling of the longitudinal mode vanishes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reaching thermal equilibrium requires that all the modes can exchange energy with each other - the weaker the coupling of the longitudinal mode is, the longer this process takes as the strength/frequency of interaction goes down, until it fully decouples as a "spurious" polarization in the massless case.

Comment: If we substitute exactly $\mu=0$, then they can't even exchange energy with this mode, right? So it can only exchange energy with the other 2 degrees of freedom which shouldn't take $\infty$ time. I mean the time is large only if $\mu$ is very small and non-zero. If it is exactly zero the time should be small only.

Comment: @KasiReddySreemanReddy Zee's whole point is that you cannot experimentally distinguish "the mass is zero and we've reached equilibrium of 2 modes quickly" and "the mass is very small and we're very far from reaching equilibrium with the third mode because of small coupling", because they both *look* like equilibrium of two modes.